# wxPython: scope of menu key shortcuts and dynamic disabling

Tags: python, menu, wxpython, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Python 2.7.2 and wxPython 2.8.12.1 on Arch Linux x86_64.

I'd like to make the following example work this way:
* when left TextCtrl (`text_A`) has focus, by pressing `Shift+A` it should execute `do_A()`, and by pressing `Shift+B` it should write `B` in the text area; also, `menu.foo.bar_B` should be disabled (and `menu.foo.bar_A` enabled)
* when right TextCtrl (`text_B`) has focus, by pressing `Shift+A` it should write `A` in the text area, and by pressing `Shift+B` it should execute `do_B()`; also, `menu.foo.bar_A` should be disabled (and `menu.foo.bar_B` enabled)

```
import wx


class Foo(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(600, 480))

        self.init_menu()
        self.init_text()

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def init_menu(self):
        self.menu = wx.MenuBar()
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menu)

        self.menu.foo = wx.Menu()
        self.menu.Append(self.menu.foo, "&Foo")

        self.menu.foo.bar_A = self.menu.foo.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Bar&A\tShift+A")
        self.menu.foo.bar_B = self.menu.foo.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Bar&B\tShift+B")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.handle_A, self.menu.foo.bar_A)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.handle_B, self.menu.foo.bar_B)

    def init_text(self):
        self.box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.box)

        self.text_A = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.text_B = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.box.Add(self.text_A, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.box.Add(self.text_B, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

    def handle_A(self, event):
        print('A')

    def handle_B(self, event):
        print('B')

app = wx.App()
Foo()
app.MainLoop()
```

Binding to the menu event with something like `self.text_A.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.handle_A, self.menu.foo.bar_A)` doesn't work at all.

Should I make use `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS` and `wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS` to bind/unbind the menu items, set/reset the shortcut keys and enable/disable menu entries? It sounds complicated for larger applications, in general I'd like to know what's the proper (most frequent, clean and tidy) way wxPython applications limit the scope of menu shortcut keys and dynamically enable/disable menu items.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up an article about menus a few years ago: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/07/02/wxpython-working-with-menus-toolbars-and-accelerators/

It talks about disabling menus in there. There's also an example in the wxPython demo package about this. I think you have to bind the menu events to the frame object though so binding them to the text control probably won't work. I do think the focus event is probably a better place to do the enable/disable bit though.

To unbind an event, use the UnBind method. See http://zetcode.com/wxpython/events/ or http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.EvtHandler-class.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks for all those references, actually the most interesting part for what I want to do is probably the *Update* part at the end of your article, which mentions `wxUpdateUIEvent`: do you know some good examples from which I can learn to use it? After a brief Google search I couldn't find many...

Comment: I haven't really used it that much. I think I got that from either the wxPython demo or the mailing list. Feel free to ask there as well.